# Passing posts view id to another controller so I can access table records in Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

So I got posts page, where I have my post. The post has ID which leads to posts table. For it I have PostsController where everything is accessible thru $post->id, $post->name etc.

But I have another table named orders and on submit button, it needs some of the information from posts table by id.

[I have post with url posts/{id} and there's submit button in the view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skmF6.png)

The button needs to get $post information to OrdersController with submit information.

I've tried this in OrdersController

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
    ]);

    $post = Post::all();
    $order = new Order;
    $order->client = Auth::user()->name;
    $order->phone = Auth::user()->phone;
    $order->vehicle = $post->id;
    $order->date_from = $request->input('date_from');
    $order->save();

    return redirect('/posts')->with('success', 'Rezervēts');
}
```

$posts = Post::all(); is getting all array information from table but cannot use specific id.

And I have this in PostsController

```
   public function show($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $images = Image::All();
        return view('posts.show')->with(compact('post', 'images'));
    }
```

[Route for show function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dMlk.png)

Error that I'm getting with shown code: Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

Expected results:
[orders table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4JOH.png)

Error: Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.
Problem: Can't get exact id from view to another controller, so I can access posts table records that I need from OrdersController.

Ps. I've been thru most of the pages on this error, but can't seem to find the one that would help.

Comment: Post is a [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-collections) (basically an array) of multiple post objects.

Comment: Okay, I understand that. But the question is: if my post/view is with id 28, how can I get array information where id = 28?

Comment: You could add the id as a parameter to the route or in a hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

I would modify the route so that the affected post.

Route:

```
Route::post('/order/{post}/store', 'OrderController@store')->name('order.store');
```

Controller (store method):

```
public function store(Post $post, Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
    ]);

    $order = new Order;
    $order->client = Auth::user()->name;
    $order->phone = Auth::user()->phone;
    $order->vehicle = $post->id;
    $order->date_from = $request->input('date_from');
    $order->save();

    return redirect('/posts')->with('success', 'Rezervēts');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thanks. 
Solved: `{{ Form::hidden('id', $post->id) }}` in view. 
Controller: `$post = Post::findorfail($request->id);` 
Then: `$post->(whatever you need from table)`